# Amend part of a class name with a number when clicking on a numerical keypad JS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to create a Front end Class picker, so clients can view what a page style might look like on the Front end before committing to it in the CMS, like a page style preview panel.

I have built a very quick and crude UI number pad from 1 - 10.  The name of the page styles are grid-style-1, grid-style-2 etc etc (1-10) and depending on which numnber you click on the keypad, that will change the number at the end of the class.  The Class incidentally is applied to the html at the top of the page.

```
<div class="style-picker">
<div class="picker-window">
    <div class="style-display">
    <h2>Grid Style<span></span></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="controlpad-wrapper">
        <ol class="digit-wrapper">
            <li id="digit-1" class="digit">1</li>
            <li id="digit-2" class="digit">2</li>
            <li id="digit-3" class="digit">3</li>
            <li id="digit-4" class="digit">4</li>
            <li id="digit-5" class="digit">5</li>
            <li id="digit-6" class="digit">6</li>
            <li id="digit-7" class="digit">7</li>
            <li id="digit-8" class="digit">8</li>
            <li id="digit-9" class="digit">9</li>
            <li id="digit-10" class="digit">10</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
<script>
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-1");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-2");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-3");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-4').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-4");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-5').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-5");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-6').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-6");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-7').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-7");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-8').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-8");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-9').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-9");
});
$('.style-picker .digit-wrapper #digit-10').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html").addClass("grid-style-10");
});
```

So far I can only get the name of each class to appear on click so I'm left with a string of class names, but I can't get the previous class to disappear - but I assume there would be an easier way of looping through this and just amending the last digit of the class instead, can't quite work it out yet.

Any thoughts or help would be massively appreciated!

Best Regards

Simon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up simple version.

The click event will get the id and remove all classes from body and add the new class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".digit",function(e){
     key = e.target.id.replace("digit-","");
     $("body").removeClass().addClass("grid-style-" + key)
   });
});
```

```css
.grid-style-1{background:red;}
.grid-style-2{background:green;}
.grid-style-3{background:blue;}
.grid-style-4{background:black;}
.grid-style-5{background:teal;}
.grid-style-6{background:silver;}
.grid-style-7{background:gold;}
.grid-style-8{background:orange;}
.grid-style-9{background:#00aaff;}
.grid-style-10{background:#aaff33;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="style-picker">
<div class="picker-window">
    <div class="style-display">
    <h2>Grid Style<span></span></h2>

    </div>
    <div class="controlpad-wrapper">
        <ol class="digit-wrapper">
            <li id="digit-1" class="digit">1</li>
            <li id="digit-2" class="digit">2</li>
            <li id="digit-3" class="digit">3</li>
            <li id="digit-4" class="digit">4</li>
            <li id="digit-5" class="digit">5</li>
            <li id="digit-6" class="digit">6</li>
            <li id="digit-7" class="digit">7</li>
            <li id="digit-8" class="digit">8</li>
            <li id="digit-9" class="digit">9</li>
            <li id="digit-10" class="digit">10</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```